# Virtualmin backups - Strange blank "Files" within backup that cannot be read

Tags: hosting, file

I have setup a Virtualmin backup that appears to be working correctly.

However, when the backups are attempted to be extracted there is a large amount of errors. WinRAR error below:

[image: WinRAR errors]

This appears to be due to blank "Files" in most folders of the backup that WinRAR says cannot be extracted. These "Files" do not appear in Filezilla when browsing to the same directory on the server. Please see the images for more information:

[image: Filezilla no blank "Files"]

[image: Blank "Files" in backup]

Does anyone know what these files may be, and whether this is normal, including receiving many errors when extracting the backup?

Thank you
Matt